# UIButton and UILabel not clickable on smaller screens

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I created a custom dropdown which is stack view of UIButtons. And made a tappable part of UIlabel text (Terms of Service).
Both are perfectly working(can tap on them) on iphone XR.

The problem occurs just on smaller devices(iphone 6,7). Last UIButton in dropdown is tappable just above the button title and not on label or on whole button space. UILabel(Terms of Service) is completely not tappable.
Iphone XR is working perfectly.

[Not clickable UIButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4sX8.png)

[Not clickable UILabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEcY3.png)

**Listening for UILabel tap(not called on smaller devices):**

```
 @objc func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("TapLabel")
    let text = "By upgrading your account, you agree to our Terms of Service."
    let termsRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "Terms of Service.")

    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: textTerms, inRange: termsRange) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxx/terms") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    } else {
        print("Tapped none")
    }
}
```

**Interface-builder:**
[Interface overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw1wr.png)

Layout Constraints log, when I open up a dropdown:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823f4230 UIButton:0x109505a70'Quarterly Subscription - ...'.height == 50   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823f5680 V:[UIButton:0x10950d760'Quarterly Subscription - ...']-(0)-[UIButton:0x109505a70'Quarterly Subscription - ...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823f5a40 V:[UIButton:0x109505a70'Quarterly Subscription - ...']-(0)-[UIButton:0x10950d260'Monthly Subscription - 13...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823f48c0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIButton:0x10950d760'Quarterly Subscription - ...']-(0)-[UIButton:0x10950d260'Monthly Subscription - 13...']   (active)>"
)

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823f4230 UIButton:0x109505a70'Quarterly Subscription - ...'.height == 50   (active)>
```

Any ideas, what can be the cause of this behaviour ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have set width & height of label/button relative to superviews, due to which their size is very small or other views come on top of them

1. Give some background color to label & button and check it on smaller screen you’ll know the issue then
2. See their view heirarchy in debug mode

Comment: Thank you, the problem were just in small or not set heights of containers. The problem was more visible by using hierarchy debug,